# $x^a-x^b$ is odd function, and $1 \leq a,b, \leq 100$

Tags: even-and-odd-functions

How many ordered pairs of positive integers $(a, b)$ with $1 \le a, b \le 100$ exist such that the function $f(x) = x^a - x^b$ is an odd function.

I know that a function is only odd iff both $a$ and $b$ are odd, and there are $50$ odd numbers in between $1$ and $100$ inclusive. Therefore, I think that the answer is 2500 (this includes the case where $a=b$ because $f(x)=0$ is also an odd function). However, this is wrong. I do not know what I am doing wrong, possibly with the restriction. Can anyone identity my error?

Comment: If $a=b$ are **even**, the given function is odd.

Comment: What about the cases where $a=b$ and both are even?

Comment: Ahh, thank you for the catch. So it should be 2500+50=2550.